# there will be/ is going to be

Tags: future-tense

I want to say that tomorrow there will be a workshop.
is this sentence grammatically correct:

> tomorrow is going to be a workshop

Sounds to me that tomorrow is that workshop itself...

is there another form for this? 
thanks.

Comment: You could say “There will be a workshop tomorrow/I think I’ll organize a workshop tomorrow” as an immediate decision

Answer (score 2):

You're on the right track.  I would go with

> Tomorrow there's (there is) going to be a workshop

Because, like you said, your phrasing implies that the notion of tomorrow is itself a workshop.

As a practical note, "there's" can be pronounced rather silently and sound a lot like "is", so if you've been listening to spoken english, that could explain your confusion.